# distinct on several columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a query in postgresql which eliminates duplicate rows based on the value on a subset of columns.
Let's assume that my database is as follows:

```
name var1 var2 var3
   a    1   2   10
   a    1   2   26
   b    3   56  47
   c    4   78  50
```

For my purposes I would like to drop the second row (or the first one, it doesn't really matter) in order to have the table as:

```
name var1 var2 var3
   a    1   2   10
   b    3   56  47
   c    4   78  50
```

I have tried withe the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT on (name, var1, var2)
FROM table;
```

but without any success, can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, but you also need to specify what you want to select, not only on which columns to apply uniqueness to:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT ON (name, var1, var2)
  name,
  var1,
  var2,
  var3
FROM
  table
-- ORDER BY name, var1, var2, var3 (ASC or DESC)
```

Since you don't care which record stays, there's no need for `ORDER BY` but generally you would want to specify ordering to pick the right row.

Comment: Thank you, in case I need to specify which data has to stay, the sql procedure will drop the second observation that finds, right?

Comment: Yes, the statement will return rows based on ORDER BY condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `min` with `max` if you want to fetch the maximum of the two values

```
select name, var1, var2, min(var3) from your_table
group by name, var1, var2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name, var1, var2) name, var1, var2, var3
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    name, var1, var2, var3;
```

[image]

### Demo

The critical thing here is to always use an `ORDER BY` clause when using `DISTINCT ON` in Postgres.  The reason is that the `ORDER BY` clause will be used to determine which is the "first" record which should be retained from the `DISTINCT ON` operation.